# How to move iMovie projects from iPhone to a computer for storage?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, imovie

I have a bunch of iMovie projects on my iPhone and they take up quite a bit of space.  I'd like to move them to my Windows PC.

In iTunes I tried going to Device/Apps/Sharing/iMovie, but it seems you can only add things to iMovie - you can't retrieve them from iOS.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike music and photos there (seems to be, IMHO) is no built-in sync option for iMovie. You may need to use a program like iExplorer to get the actual project files off the IOS device but once you have them there is no guarantee that they will be usable in any application (Mac or Windows).

If you tap the share button in iMovie you can then save the final project as a movie file right to the camera roll which will then sync to your PC the next time you sync your device. But from your question it seems that you want a backup of all of the individual files contained in each iMovie project.

I would bet that a backup of your iPhone contains all of those files but never having actually used iMovie on an IOS device I can't say so authoritatively. But again an application like iExplorer will let you (ahem...) explore the backups on your PC to verify and extract those files.

Comment: OK I went looking a little further and it seems that if you have iMovie 10.1 you are in luck as you can send the project via iCloud and other conduits to your computer. No surprise tho as these require a Mac. iMore has the details: http://www.imore.com/how-move-imovie-project-your-iphone-or-ipad-your-mac